# Should I restate my hypothesis? (interaction)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction

Suppose I have the following model:

$Y = α + β1∗education + β2∗gender + β3∗gender∗education$

Gender = 1 if male (reference group = 0 female)

---

Based on the theory I develop the following two hypothesis:

- H1) Higher educated males have a significant positive association with Y
- H2) There is no significant relation between educated women and Y

---

**Question**

What I know is that

- β1 = the effect of education for females
- β3 = the *difference* in effect of education for males (interaction)
- β1 + β3 = the effect of education for males

Since **β3** concerns the difference in effect, is my hypothesis consistent with my model i.e. can I draw a conclusion on the hypothesis purely based on the p value of coefficients of **β1** and **β3** in the model? Or do I have to restate my hypothesis to something like ''...the effect of education for males is stronger than females...'' or run two separate regressions to make a conclusion on this hypothesis?

For Hypothesis H1 I can directly read the Pvalue on the coefficient of **β1**. But how would that work out for **β3**? I dont think I can combine it in some way with **β1**

Comment: In any case it is not possible to test H2. What's a "sigificant relation"? What you're actually asserting in this hypothesis is that the relationship is exactly 0, but no amount of data can ever tell you whether a relationship is exactly 0 or is just really really small. The best you can do is state a hypothesis "There is a significant relationship between educated women and Y" and then fail to find evidence for it.

Comment: @denziloe but shouldnt the hypothesis support the theory? I actually research the effect of a variable after a law reform. The current theory implies that there is no relation before the new law, but there is after the new law. What would be the best way to formulate in this case?

Comment: A hypothesis should state that an effect exists. You test it by examining the null hypothesis, which states that no effect exists. If these ideas are unfamiliar to you, you need to read up on hypothesis testing before you can understand what you are doing here.